# replaceWith Issue with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with **IE8** and the `replaceWith()` method of jQuery (in fact with other methods too).

I try to replace a section with an **AJAX** call response, but IE doesn't change anything at all.
The script works on **Firefox 22** but in **IE8** nothing moved.

I also try with `html()` methods, and same, it only appear once in the script.

Here the refresh function code

```
refresh= function(section, url_rel) {
        var success=false;
        $.ajax({ 
            url : url_rel,
            type : 'GET',
            data : '',
            dataType : 'html',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success : function(code_html, statut){ 
                if(code_html !='') {        
                    var parent = section.parent();
                    section.replaceWith(code_html);                 
                    parent.find('.modify,.suppress').each(function() { 
                        initContextMenu($(this));
                    });
                    updateHour();
                    success=true;
                }
                else {
                    alert('Une erreur est survenue...');
                }
            }
        });
        return success;
    }
```

This function is called several times on the webpage but failed once..

Thanks in advance

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing in the firebug console and no error in the ie status bar

Comment: IE8 also has a console (press F12 to bring up the dev tools) it might give you more info than just relying on the status bar.

Comment: Which tab can be useful ? I only have HTML, CSS, Script and Profileur

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on this line : section.replaceWith(code_html) and run debug mode, it becomes red, but no error message

Comment: well, if this is your exact code, the bit at the end of that line that says `AJAX` looks a bit suspect. Also, it might be good to confirm that `code_html` contains what you're expecting it to and that it doesn't contain any invalid HTML.

Comment: Yeah it was a bad removed comment, but when I try an alert to see what is code_html, the content is right, juste the replaceWith which doesn't work

Comment: Does `code_html` contain any HTML5 elements? Or any other broken/invalid HTML? Also, have you tried it in IE9 or IE10? (the dev tools in later IE versions are much better than in IE8, so if you can get the same error in those versions, it will be easier to debug). Oh, and another thought... what jQuery version are you using? (note that jQuery v2 does not support IE8; you need to stick with v1.x)

Comment: Hum yes the code_html contain section tags, and I think it doesn't work in other IE version but I'm not sure. And yes I have the 1.10.1 version of jQuery

Comment: Yeah, it could well be the section tags doing it. Try removing/changing the html5 bits and see if that helps. Are you using html5shiv or modernizr? You need to use one of them in order to use html5 elements in old IE.

Comment: Hum well, when I looked in the source, I found that something was wrong. And of course it was something really stupid.. <li>blabla</div> Now it works :D. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: heh, easily done. :-)